# Importing multiple csv files and extracting one column of data to form a single matrix

Tags: matlab, csv, for-loop, import

I am very new to MATLAB, so I am fairly certain that this is a very simple question. I have several output data sets, each with a prefix (e.g. PT_1 to PT_20). I would like to use a for loop to import data from the second column of each of the csv file to a new matrix and align it with time, which is constant in all files.

The input files look like

PT_1.....

```
time    param 1 param 2 param 3
2/01/2001 23:00 11.449428   3   314.322471
3/01/2001 23:00 11.448935   3   311.683002
```

PT_2.....

```
time    param 1 param 2 param 3
2/01/2001 23:00 11.445892   0   296.523937
3/01/2001 23:00 11.445393   0   294.0944
```

And I want my output to look like

```
time    PT_1    PT_2
2/01/2001 23:00 11.449428   11.445892
3/01/2001 23:00 11.448935   11.445393
```

So far the code that I've got it is

```
files = 0:1:21;
for i=1:21;
filename = sprintf('WQ_%d.csv', files(i));
origdata = importdata (filename);
end
```

I can see that it recognises the file names correctly but it doesn't really do what I want it to do, as it over writes the data with each loop. Obviously, I have the coding wrong. 
Can anyone kindly help me with figuring out how to write a suitable code for that? 
Thanks so much!

Comment: I just updated my answer as I realized your csv files appear to have header lines. If my solution doesn't work, let me know, as I had to make a few assumptions on the way through. I imagine the final answer will be very close to what I have now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
%# Set the number of csv files
DirectoryPath = 'FullDirectoryPathHereWithTrailingSlash';
NumFile = 2;

%# Open the first file and get the first column (the date column)
File1Path = [DirectoryPath, 'PT_1.csv'];
fid1 = fopen(File1Path, 'r');
Date = textscan(fid1, '%s %*[^\n]', 'Delimiter', ',', 'HeaderLines', 1);
fclose(fid1);

%Convert dates to matlab date numbers and get number of rows
Date = datenum(Date{1, 1}, 'dd/mm/yyyy');
T = size(Date, 1);

%# Preallocate a matrix to hold all the data, and add the date column
D = [Date, NaN(T, NumFile)];

%# Loop over the csv files, get the second column and add it to the data matrix
for n = 1:NumFile

    %# Get the current file name
    CurFilePath = [DirectoryPath, 'PT_', num2str(n), '.csv'];

    %# Open the current file for reading and scan in the second colum using numerical format
    fid1 = fopen(CurFilePath, 'r');
    CurData = textscan(fid1, '%*s %f %*[^\n]', 'Delimiter', ',', 'HeaderLines', 1);
    fclose(fid1);

    %Add the current data to the cell array
    D(:, n+1) = CurData{1, 1};

end
```

Hopefully the code should be self-explanatory using the comments I've provided. The one slightly tricky bit is the format strings I've used with the `textscan` function. Here is a quick explanation:

1) `'%s %*[^\n]'` says: Get the first column, which is in string format (ie `%s`) and skip all remaining columns (ie `%*[^\n]`).

2) `'%*s %f %*[^\n]'` says: Skip the first column, which is in string format (ie `%*s`), get the second column, which is a floating point number (ie `%f`), and then skip all remaining columns (ie `%*[^\n]`).

**UPDATE:** I just updated the code to include a variable at the top that allows you to specify the directory that your csv files are in (in case it is not the current directory). Just replace the text FullDirectoryPathHereWithTrailingSlash with the appropriate path, eg something like `/home/username/Documents/` on Linux, or `C:\Windows\Blah\` on Windows.

I just tested this code on two test csv files, named `PT_1.csv` and `PT_2.csv` that appear exactly like this:

```
time, param 1, param 2, param 3
2/01/2001 23:00, 11, 3, 314.322471
3/01/2001 23:00, 12, 3, 311.683002
```

and

```
time, param 1, param 2, param 3
2/01/2001 23:00, 13, 0, 296.523937
3/01/2001 23:00, 14, 0, 294.0944
```

The result?

```
>> D

D =

      730853          11          13
      730854          12          14
```

Comment: Hi Colin! Thanks for the instant reply. I went with your code and got a message saying 'Assignment has more non-singleton rhs dimensions than non-singleton subscripts'. What could this mean?                 Thanks for your help!

Comment: It's the last line of the loop, `D(:, n+1) = CurData{1,1}`

Comment: @cwick I just noticed that in the examples of the "csv" files you provide in the question, there are no commas. Are the files delimited by commas, or by white-space? or by tabs? Also, do you know how to use debug mode in Matlab? If you could pause at the last line and tell me what `CurData` looks like, that would be very helpful. It would also help if you could tell me what `D` looks like when the error occurs.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. No the values in the input file are separated by commas.

Comment: bare with me as I am a dummy to MATLAB. Several questions, 1) when the command is given to open the first file and take the first column (lines 4-7), the resulting 'Date' only contains the very first date and does not have the list of all dates.2) MATLAB gives an error of  "Error using dtstr2dtnummx, Failed on converting date string to date number" on `Date = datenum(Date{1, 1}, 'dd/mm/yyyy')`.3) `CurData` has no values and D contains a 1x2 cell array, with 1x1 being the first data and the other referring to the 2nd column data to be taken from the csv files (1x20 double).

Comment: @cwick I just updated my answer to include a variable at the top that allows you to specify the directory that the csv files are in (in case it isn't the current directory). I've also included two test csv files. The script is running fine on my machine with the test csv files. Could you please create the two test csv files in my answer on your machine and try and running it on them? If we can get it working on those test csv files on your machine, then we can go from there. Cheers.

Comment: @cwick Also, make sure you have the latest version of my code from the answer. The bit about the `HeaderLines` is particularly important, and if you are still running the original version without it, that could explain the errors.

Comment: YES! that worked! Thanks so very much. I also figured out that the dates in my input files are in the format of 2001-01-02 23:00:00, hence probably why it was giving trouble with using datenum. But i changed `Date = datenum(Date{1, 1}, 'dd/mm/yyyy')` part to `Date = datenum(Date{1, 1}, 'yyyy/mm/dd') and now it gives really odd values in the time column. But the rest of it works like a charm. Thanks a million.

Comment: @cwick I encourage you to hack around with that code and learn as much from it as you can. Also, read up on Matlab's numerical date format: You can use `datenum(Date{1, 1}, 'yyyy-mm-dd HH:MM:SS')` to get fractional numerical dates, thus also preserving the time component. Finally, if you think my answer was helpful then please click the green tick mark next to it to mark the question answered and also feel free to upvote (if you have enough reputation to do so that is - I think you need 15). Cheers.

Comment: @collin I only have 13 apparently. But will certainly upvote when I get more. I have many more questions.